# ASP.NET Core redirecting to the same page instead of HomePage

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm new to Asp .net core, I was trying to build form using CRUD opertaions.Since i'm trying to save the new data it redirecting to form action instead of homepage where my list is visible. I want my data to show on studentlist since im redirecting it to StudentList but this isnt happening. Look on the internet but couldn't find any relevant answer to it.
[Form Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCGxe.png)
[After Saving the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGQt4.png)

````
```Controller
````

```html
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebAppDotNetCoreCrudNew.Models;

namespace WebAppDotNetCoreCrudNew.Controllers
{
    public class StudentController : Controller
    {
        private readonly StudentContext _Db;
        public StudentController(StudentContext Db)
        {
            _Db = Db;
        }
        public IActionResult StudentList()
        {
            try
            {
                var stdList = from a in _Db.tbl_Student
                              join b in _Db.tbl_Department
                              on a.DepID equals
                              b.ID into Dep
                              from b in Dep.DefaultIfEmpty()

                              select new Student
                              {
                                  ID = a.ID,
                                  Name = a.Name,
                                  Fname=a.Fname,
                                  Mobile=a.Mobile,
                                  Email=a.Email,
                                  Description=a.Description,
                                  DepID=a.DepID,

                                  Department=b==null?"":b.Department
                              };

                return View(stdList);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return View();
            }
            
        }

        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            loadDDL();
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddStudent(Student obj)
        {
            try
            {
                
                if(ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    
                    if (obj.ID == 0)
                    {
                        _Db.tbl_Student.Add(obj);
                        await _Db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                    
                    return RedirectToAction("StudentList");

                }
                return View();
            }
            catch (Exception ex )
            {
                return RedirectToAction("StudentList");
            }
        }


        private void loadDDL()
        {
            try
            {
                List<Departments> depList = new List<Departments>();
                depList = _Db.tbl_Department.ToList();
                depList.Insert(0, new Departments { ID = 0, Department = "Please Select" });

                ViewBag.DepList = depList;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
@model WebAppDotNetCoreCrudNew.Models.Student

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>


<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="AddStudent">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="ID" />
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Fname" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Fname" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Fname" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Mobile" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Mobile" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Mobile" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                 <label asp-for="Department" class="control-label"></label>
                 <select asp-for="DepID" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.DepList,"ID","Department"))">

                 </select>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <a asp-action="StudentList" class="btn btn-outline-success">Student List</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>



@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: So basically, you are saving a student in`Create page`, once you successfully save it then you want to redirect to the `student list page` right?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Yes once i click on save it redirect me to AddStudent instead i want it to redirect me to list with save changes.

Comment: Glad to assist you bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

**Problem: 1:**

Have gone through your error. This is very obvious because the error clearly stated that it doesn't find the `AddStudent view` as it's not there.

**How To Resolve:**

As your `student add` view is named as `create` so your code should be as below:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddStudent(Student obj)
        {
            try
            {

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                    if (obj.ID == 0)
                    {
                        _context.Students.Add(obj);
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }

                    return RedirectToAction("StudentList");

                }
                return RedirectToAction("Create");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("StudentList");
            }
        }
```

**Note:**  You cannot write `return View()` as your `student add view` created as `Create` so after adding `new student` if you return just `View()` it will eventually encounter that error which you are currently encountering.

**Problem: 2:**

Another problem is your `ModelState.IsValid` in `AddStudent(Student obj)` will always be `false` as you have set `<input type="hidden" asp-for="ID" />` in your view which doesn't make any sense. Because in  `AddStudent page` (that is `Create` in your scenario) `ID` will always be `0` there's no point of set this as hidden which is set `ModelState.IsValid` value as false. So your code should be as below:

**Create View:**

```
@model WebAppDotNetCoreCrudNew.Models.Student

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="AddStudent">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Fname" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Fname" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Fname" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Mobile" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Mobile" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Mobile" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                 <label asp-for="Department" class="control-label"></label>
                 <select asp-for="DepID" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.DepList,"ID","Department"))">

                 </select>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <a asp-action="StudentList" class="btn btn-outline-success">Student List</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>



@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

**Controller:**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddStudent(Student obj)
        {
            try
            {

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {

                    if (obj.ID == 0)
                    {
                        _context.Students.Add(obj);
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }

                    return RedirectToAction("StudentList");

                }
                return RedirectToAction("Create");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("StudentList");
            }
        }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just change the redirect to return View() under the Add Student action

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Student obj) //change the name to create
        {
            try
            {
                
                if(ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    
                    if (obj.ID == 0)
                    {
                        _Db.tbl_Student.Add(obj);
                        await _Db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                    
                    return View(obj); //If you want to display the data that you have save otherwise just put ---> return View();

                }
                return View();
            }
            catch (Exception ex )
            {
                return View(obj);
            }
        }
```

Comment: nope i want to display the save result in default StudentList which is on my homepage

Comment: My bad. I din read it correctly. Could u use F9 key to add a break point to the redirect and run to see what is happening.

Comment: Mybad i should have write [return View(obj)].
fixed it thanks for the help.